# How to add a keyword to WebStorm so I can color it

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

So I am using TypeScript with WebStorm and I would like to do a special pink color to the keyword: `subscribe`
however as you can see it is not in the list of words.

[image]

Is there no way to add a keyword so I can custom color it?

Comment: No, there is no such possibilty.

Comment: mmm disappointing :( no way to edit some XML ?

Comment: No, the syntax highlighting is not based on any XML, it's implemented as a Java lexical analyzer. You can extend the highlighing by writing your own plugin.

Comment: mmm I see, no plugin exists already to do that?